# How to read a csv file from local network with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to read the csv file from `192.168.214.241/data/myfile.csv`

When I do

```
data = pd.read_csv('//192.168.214.241/data/myfile.csv')
```

I get the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'//192.168.214.241/data/myfile.csv' does not exist
```

The file exists though. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

**EDIT**:
Actually I might have a rights problem. When I access the folder via the Windows GUI I have to enter username and password. Can I account or that with `pd.read_csv()`?

**EDIT 2:** 
I used another PC and it worked. Non pandas/python related problem. Thanks for all the help though!

Comment: add `http:` as prefix

Comment: Adding ```http:``` results in an ```URLError:```. More precisely in ```[WinError 10060]```

Answer (score 2):

try this to see what directory you're currently in:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.listdir())
```

your code looks fine so you're probably just in the wrong place.

Comment: I am in ```C:\Users\Myself\some\path```

Comment: Do you have an idea what I should change?

Answer (score 1):

Use file URI format:

```
data = pd.read_csv('://192.168.214.241/data/myfile.csv')
```

or

```
data = pd.read_csv('file://192.168.214.241/data/myfile.csv')
```

Comment: When I do ```data = pd.read_csv('://192.168.214.241/data/myfile.csv')``` I get ```FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2]```. And when I do ```data = pd.read_csv('file://192.168.214.241/data/myfile.csv')```, I get ```URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 3]```

Comment: Actually I might have a rights problem. When I access the folder via the Windows GUI I have to enter username and password. Can I account or that with ```pd.read_csv()```?